# ASP.Net MVC3 : Steven Sanderson's tutorial -- using Ninject error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

My project errors with the global.asax Application_Start calls: **ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());**

```
namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Infrastructure
{
    public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory 
    {
        private IKernel ninjectKernel;

        public NinjectControllerFactory()
        {
            ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
            AddBindings();
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            return controllerType == null ? null : (IController)ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
        }

        private void AddBindings()
        {
            // put additional bindingers here
        }
    }
```

**ERROR STACK:**

```
Locating source for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs'. 
Checksum: MD5 {de 1d cc 43 b7 22 44 a5 8d 8b 50 ed 23 dc 4 28} 
The file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs' does not exist. 
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs'... 
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs'. 
The file was not found in a project. Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'... 
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'... 
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfcsrc\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'... 
The debugger will ask the user to find the file: c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs. 
The user pressed Cancel in the Find Source dialog. 
The debug source files settings for the active solution have been modified so that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs. 
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Multimap.cs'.
```

Comment: By the way I did add a reference to the Ninject 4.0 client in my WebUI project.

Comment: Have you tried using the Ninject.MVC3 nuget package? http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Ninject.MVC3/2.2.2.0

Comment: Did you follow the installation procedure? As far as I know Steven gave an example where you can use Install-Package Ninject -Project SportsStore.WebUI to install Ninject and to reference it immediately?

Comment: Yes, I did follow the procedure in the book:  Install-Package Ninject -Project SportsStore.WebUI

Comment: I have not tried the Ninject MVC3 nuget package ... I'm following the instructions in Sanderson's book.  Install-Package Ninject -Project SportsStore.WebUI

Comment: If that does not work, try removing the Ninject reference from SportsStore.WebUI (and I think it is also added to unit test and model project). Go to http://ninject.org/download and download it from there. And then add a reference manually to the newly downloaded Ninject DLL. I did not have that problem that you mention so it is quite strange that you are getting those error messages.

Comment: Which of the dlls did you use ...??? the 4.0 client, 4.0 full ???

Comment: Also, saw a page on the web suggesting I uninstall and reinstall from Manage Nuget package and add Ninject manually.  This placed the reference into my project but still had the same problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest to use the official Ninject MVC3 extension. The NuGet package Ninject.MVC3 will setup everything for you so that you can start to inject depenencies into your controllers.

Replacing the controller factory isn't the prefered way anymore for MVC3. With this release the proposed approch by the MVC development team is to use a DependencyResolver instead. The Ninject MVC3 extension uses this approach.

Read the documentation at https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3 for more information.

Comment: Right on! 100%... My 2 cents :) Then seperate your dependencies out in to a seperate project an use modules.

Comment: I tried the Ninject MVC3 extension, but I'm still getting the same problem that ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel() is returning null and the

Comment: Sorry, didn't finish correctly.  the statement 'private IKernel ninjectKernal is returning NULL and the ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel is stating that it cand find the Multimap.cs ??????

Comment: I rebuilt and ran again and this time it's stating it can't find: StandardKernel.cs

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace? What you provided so far is just the probing to resolve the source file which does not help at all.