# Mono, ASP.NET MVC 3, Ninject and a default constructor required

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mono, ninject, monodevelop, ninject.web.mvc

I have a working Visual Studio project that I want to run o Mac with Mono and MonoDevelop. 
The project is an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with Ninject MVC that basically inject on controller some interface implementations.

After add all ASP.NET MVC dlls and Ninject dependencies to the project, it compiles successfully. But when I go to run it, I have the error:

Default constructor not found for type WebActivatorTest.Controllers.HomeController.

My controller has the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    INotifier _notifier;
    public HomeController(INotifier notifier_)
    {
        _notifier = notifier_;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = _notifier.Person();

        return View();
    }

}
```

I dont wanna have an empty constructor, cause I now have an AppStart code registering my interface:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
     kernel.Bind<WebActivatorTest.Models.INotifier>().To<WebActivatorTest.Models.Notifier>();
}
```

This code works perfectly on Windows/Visual Studio but does not work on Mono.
Could some one help me?

The full error is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application

Default constructor not found for type WebActivatorTest.Controllers.HomeController.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type     WebActivatorTest.Controllers.HomeController.
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory+DefaultControllerActivator.Create (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.Type controllerType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.9 (tarball Tue Mar 20 15:31:37 EDT 2012); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: What Mono version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No parameterless constructor object defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916012/no-parameterless-constructor-object-defined)

Comment: The fact that Ninject isnt mentioned in the exception [that you didnt post] stronly suggests that MVC has not been correctly informed of you and Ninject's desire to take charge of controller creation. The reason you dint find the dup and it took me ages to find one is that you didnt show the exact exception message - it saves a lot of time if you cna remeber to add that key detail in future...

Comment: There is not duplicated parameterless constructor....

Comment: Sorr for not being clearer - AIUI there is a duplicated question (linked above) - 'I'm using Ninject with MVC and MVC is telling me I need a parameterless constructor'

Answer (score 0):

you can add default constructor

```
public HomeController()
{
}
```

But i think, you wrong activate Ninject for controllers. You need register ninject factory. Make sure your code in Global.asax like below:

```
 public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the global filters.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filters">The filters.</param>
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the routes.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="routes">The routes.</param>
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            return kernel;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when the application is started.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
        {
            base.OnApplicationStarted();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

Also, for examples you can see sample code on MVC3 [here](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/tree/master/mvc3/src/SampleApplication%22Here%22)

Comment: I dont wanna have an empty constructor.

Comment: My Global.asax is not registering Ninject Factory... cause the project has an AppStart/NinjectMV3.cs that does the work. 

Ninject was installed with NuGet os Visual Studio that installs it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the [MVC extensions](http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3) for ninject, as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271839/asp-net-mvc3-steven-sandersons-tutorial-using-ninject-error)

I'm assuming this will work with Mono

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming a little late to the party, but this solution helped me.

Override the default constructor:

```
public HomeController() : this(new Notifier())
{

}

public HomeController(INotifier notifier_)
{
    _notifier = notifier_;
}
```